# Tap here to make sure Cortana can hear you

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, cortana

When I click on the microphone icon in the Cortana search box on my Asus laptop running Windows 10 x64 16299.98 I don't hear the tone that Cortana normally plays when she used to do when she listening to me (and continues to do on my work laptop and my Lumia 950).  Instead I see **Tap here** to make sure Cortana can hear you

I don't have the greatest built-in microphone in the world, but when I've tried the voice test number on Skype I can hear myself okay.  I would expect that if Cortana couldn't hear me I'd hear the "Sorry about that I didn't hear anything." message.

I've followed the **Tap here**  link to both the "I can't hear Cortana" and "Cortana can't hear me."  If I follow "I can't hear Cortana" I get taken to this:

[image: Speaker Properties]

I don't see anything to change (and I can hear the test sounds it plays afterward).

If I follow the link to "Cortana can't hear me" I get taken to:

[image: Mike Settings]

but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: update Windows, you use an extremely old 1709 patchlevel

Comment: And check for any updated drivers for your system. Not just audio: update ALL the drivers.

Comment: I worked and worked and manage to get my system upgraded.  Some of the files required to install updates themselves were corrupted and it fixed my problem.